# How to see qpdfview annotations in other pdf readers?

Tags: pdf, qpdfview

I am using `qpdfview` to create annotations to a PDF. These however cannot be seen in Acrobat Reader, the software the OP to which I'm sending the document is using. How can I produce a document that contains the annotations in other software? The annotations cannot be seen in `xpdf` or other tools.